# Jenkins pipeline Script to create build output directory

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins version - v2.73.2 and Jenkins pipeline - 2.5 and i have a scenario where after build is completed the output .dll files are stored in the Jenkins Slave machine below bin path

```html
C:\jenkins\Test-Build\sample1\bin , script;
C:\jenkins\Test-Build\sample2\bin , package , obj, users; 
C:\jenkins\Test-Build\sample3\bin, common, views; 
C:\jenkins\Test-Build\sample4\bin, properties, fonts etc
```

Now i want to create a new directory 'Build_output' in C:\jenkins\Test-Build and copy the build output .dll files along with folders structure as

```html
C:\jenkins\Test-Build\Build_output\sample1\bin
C:\jenkins\Test-Build\Build_output\sample2\bin
C:\jenkins\Test-Build\Build_output\sample3\bin
C:\jenkins\Test-Build\Build_output\sample4\bin
```

Is there a way to handle this using pipeline script feature or do i need to write groovy code. Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

Below command may help you

```
msbuild foo.sln /p:OutDir="C:\jenkins\Test-Build\Build_output"
```